# System.Device.Location.GeoCoordinateWatcher.Position.Location.Speed always is NaN

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, windows-phone-8, geolocation

I'm making a simple app for my WP8.1 device, which will be track my maximum speed. I'm using System.Device.Location.GeoCoordinateWatcher for this. I can detect my position, but speed always is NaN. And I don't understand, why. What is wrong? Thanks for any help or info. It is my full code below:

```
namespace SpeedTracker
{
    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        GeoCoordinateWatcher watcher;
        double maxSpeed = 0.0;

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();            
    }

    private void StartTrackingBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.watcher = new GeoCoordinateWatcher(GeoPositionAccuracy.Default);

        this.watcher.MovementThreshold = 10;
        this.watcher.StatusChanged += new EventHandler<GeoPositionStatusChangedEventArgs>(watcher_StatusChanged);
        this.watcher.PositionChanged += new EventHandler<GeoPositionChangedEventArgs<GeoCoordinate>>(watcher_PositionChanged);

        this.watcher.Start();
    }

    private void StopTrackingBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.watcher.StatusChanged -= new EventHandler<GeoPositionStatusChangedEventArgs>(watcher_StatusChanged);
        this.watcher.PositionChanged -= new EventHandler<GeoPositionChangedEventArgs<GeoCoordinate>>(watcher_PositionChanged);

        this.watcher.Stop();
    }

    private void watcher_PositionChanged(object sender, GeoPositionChangedEventArgs<GeoCoordinate> e)
    {
        if (this.watcher.Position.Location.IsUnknown != true)
        {
            Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
            {
                this.maxSpeed = Math.Max(this.maxSpeed, e.Position.Location.Speed);
                this.SpeedValueTxblck.Text = this.maxSpeed.ToString();
            });
        }
        else
        {
            this.SpeedValueTxblck.Text = "Please wait while your prosition is determined...";
        }
    }

    private void watcher_StatusChanged(object sender, GeoPositionStatusChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.Status)
        {
            case GeoPositionStatus.Disabled:
                Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
                {
                    this.SpeedValueTxblck.Text = "Location Service is not enabled on the device";
                });
                break;

            case GeoPositionStatus.NoData:
                Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
                {
                    this.SpeedValueTxblck.Text = "The Location Service is working, but it cannot get location data";
                });
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    private void GetLocationCourseAndSpeed()
    {
        this.watcher.TryStart(true, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000));

        if (watcher.Position.Location.IsUnknown != true)
        {
            GeoCoordinate coord = watcher.Position.Location;

            this.maxSpeed = Math.Max(this.maxSpeed, coord.Speed);

            this.SpeedValueTxblck.Text = this.maxSpeed.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            this.SpeedValueTxblck.Text = "Unknown";
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe that there is an issue with your code. I am doing a similar function on a device that has WiFi, Cellular and GPS installed. It appears that cellular is the fastest to lock in and does not ever provide any speed data. However, when I disable cell and WiFi, I get speed data from the GPS sensor just fine. If you have dedicated GPS, I would try doing the same thing. If not, you may need it to get what you are looking for.